# C# - EF 6 - MySQL: Error when calling method from unit test method

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

I have a solution, containing more than one project. Until now everything worked quiet well, even calling methods from referenced projects.

Now I tried to start using unit tests, so I could test different methods without running to whole overhead of GUI and so on.

I have a Form1 wich creates an instance of an entity model. This model is created from a MySQL Database. Instancing from Form1 does work without a problem, when I start the Form-Project. But when I reference everything in my unit test project, and just instance Form1, EF seems to have a problem. What I get is an instace of my entity model containing the following:

*edit: The error I get is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ((SELECT
CASE WHEN (`Extent2`.`ID` IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END AS ' at line 188

I managed to see that SOME lists are filled, others are not. But what I really don't understand is, why when called from project1, the whole thing works, and called from another project, referencing project1, it results in that error.

For example: table1.toList() works and table2.toList() gives the above error. But ONLY when called from project2.

*edit2: I managed to nail it down

The line causing an error is:

```
technikerListe = entities.mitarbeiter.
            Where(m => MitarbeiterIdListe.Contains(m.ID) && m.aktiv == "Y")....
```

(where entities is my model instance)

But when I get a list of entries in the mitarbeiter table like this

```
List<mitarbeiter> mitarbeiterList = entities.mitarbeiter.ToList();
```

end then try to get the above by using

```
technikerListe = mitarbeiterList.
            Where(m => MitarbeiterIdListe.Contains(m.ID) && m.aktiv == "Y")....
```

it works.

Seems, after all, that this could be a lazy loading problem?

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I've read your question a couple of times now and I cannot see what your error is, you just seem to have explained what is going on not what is wrong?

Comment: Edited the question after trying to nail down the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is basically a feature, not a bug. It's called `Lazy-loading`. EF won't load any data from the DB if you don't ask it too. Consider following example:

```
using(var ctx = MyCoolContext("ConnectionString")) 
{
    var query = ctx.Bugs;
    var result = query.ToList(); // <= fetching the data is done here!
}
```

The actual behavior is that EF will only run the query against the server when you are enumerating the results (which is done with `.ToList()` above).

So the statements you posted above is basically just the query EF is going to send to MySQL when you'll finally tell it to.

Edit:

---

Reading your error I guess that you are trying to materialize multiple N to M relation (maybe with `.Include()` ?) which is causing problems with the latest EF 6.1.2 release when used with the latest MySQL connector. Is it possible that you're using different versions of EF in your two projects? Can you try downgrading to EF 6.1.1?

Again, please provide more information, what query is failing?

Comment: This is endeed very helpful for my overall understanding. But I don't think, that this is the issue.

Two Projects: Windows Form and Windows Service. Instancing the form calls a method, instancing a entity model. From there on I can work with the model and instance lists etc. not a problem. When I call the same method, the form is calling, to instance the entity model, from the service project, I get the above, eventhough all references are set and should work. Could the problem be with the app config, or with the fact, that there is no model in the service project?

Comment: Do you get any error when calling `anyOfYourCollections.ToList()`?

Comment: Yes, This is, when I get the exception. The model is being instanced without an error. But when filling any list, I get the error. This is when I looked into the object and saw the above.

Comment: Which exception? Please post it in your question.

Comment: It was a version problem. When downgrading from 6.1.2 to 6.1.1 it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I think we're quite a bunch of people to encounter that problem; could you make your vote on the EF Issue? http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2694